# Unity 5 - how to toggle realtime global illumination

Tags: unity, global-illumination

I am using Unity 5.5. Is there a way to enable and disable precomputed realtime GI at runtime? and if so, how can I do it?

The idea is that I want to set dynamic lights as a graphics quality option that the player can choose to toggle.

Comment: This answer on Unity Answers might be a useful starting point: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/359345/view.html

Comment: thanks, looks like there is no straightforward API solution for this.